# Using libpq (PostgreSQL) library in VS 2012 project

Tags: c++, postgresql, visual-studio-2012, lnk2019, libpq

I'm using a VS 2012 with Windows 7 x64. My friend wrote for me C++ class which is using libpq:

```
...
#include <libpq-fe.h>
const char* QStrToCStr(QString qstring);
void ShowInfoBox(QString string);
QString IToQS(int x);
QString DToQS(double x);

class BinderHandler
{
private:
    PGresult* DBResultPointer;
    PGconn* DBConnPointer;
...
}
void BinderHandler::DBConnect()
{
    DBConnPointer = PQsetdbLogin(this->pghost,this->pgport,
                                 this->pgoptions,this->pgtty,
                                 this->dbName,this->login,this->pwd);
}
...
```

I'm getting LNK2019 error each time when I try to build project. [screenshot](http://imgur.com/Q68Yj2H) I have postgres installed and I loaded some paths to project properties: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFWl7.jpg)
I'm hoping that you can give me a quick guide how make his code work which my project.

Comment: Please include the relevant information in the screenshot with your post.  Or include the screenshot themselves into your post.  [How to post images](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images)

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly specify the additional lib, libpq.lib, in Linker - Input to be linked, rather than provide the library path only.